# Use validation class outside route laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have web app, the app 50% use ajax for making request

And I want to combine ajax routes into one. Example :

I have routes like this

```
Route::prefix('post')
                 ->middleware(['verify_origin', 'only_ajax'])
                 ->name('post.')
                 ->group(function() {

                    Route::post('save-user-profile', 'User\ProfileSettingController@updateProfile')->name('saveUserProfile');
                    Route::post('save-user-social-media', 'User\ProfileSettingController@updateSocialMedia')->name('saveUserSocialMedia');
                    Route::post('save-user-avatar', 'User\ProfileSettingController@updateAvatar')->name('saveUserAvatar');
                    Route::post('save-user-account', 'User\AccountSettingController@updateAccount')->name('saveUserAccount');

            });
```

I want to wrap, all method on `post` prefix to one controller

Like this

```
function handlePost($method) {
   call_user_func($method);
}
```

Usage : `handlePost('saveUserProfile')`

Above, the method use call action `saveUserProfile`, the method `saveUserProfile` using validation class.

How to call method, but still use validation class

Comment: I don't know if this is a good idea. Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: @Phiter in my opinion it's impossible, maybe there is a solution here?

Answer (score 1):

You can have 1 route for instance `save-user` that might be a single controller class:

```
Route::prefix('post')
             ->middleware(['verify_origin', 'only_ajax'])
             ->name('post.')
             ->group(function() {

                Route::post('save-user', 'User\ProfileSettingController')->name('saveUserProfile');

        });
```

Then on the `__invoke` method inside the controller determine what kind of action needs to be triggered (probably will be passed by an `action` attribute etc...) and call the appropriate method.